# Prevent multiple events using MutationObserver

Tags: javascript, jquery, mutation-observers

I want to track a dynamic value of an input using jquery and trigger events depending on the progression (25%, 50%, 75% and 100%). In my case, the input is a progress bar:
[Progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L33Jl.jpg)
Here is the html code, knowing that aria-valuetext is dynamic:

```
<input tabindex="0" type="range" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="slide progress" aria-valuetext="30%">
```

To do so, I use the MutationObserver interface:

```
//Select the target node
const target = document.querySelector("[aria-valuetext]");
//create an observer instance
const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, e){
    let videoProgress = Math.round($("[aria-valuetext]").val()/1000);
    if(videoProgression == 25){console.log('Progression:', videoProgression);
        console.log('Video action: Progression 25%');}
    if(videoProgression == 50){console.log('Progression:', videoProgression);
        console.log('Video action: Progression 50%');}
    if(videoProgression == 75){console.log('Progression:', videoProgression);
        console.log('Video action: Progression 75%');}
    if(videoProgression == 100){console.log('Progression:', videoProgression);
        console.log('Video action: Progression 100%');}
});
const config = {attributes: true, childlist: true, characterData: true};
observer.observe(target, config);
```

My issue is that the events are fired multiple times. I tried to use preventDefault and StopImmediatePropagation without any result.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you wanna track the input value using an `onchange` or `oninput` event?

`MutationObserver` seems a bit overkill and is intended to fire an event on every DOM mutation. You can stop observing using its [`.disconnect()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/disconnect) and start observing again using the `.observe()` method.

Can you add some more clarifications regarding your requirements? Which problem do you want to solve, exactly?

Comment: Thank you ˈvɔlə for your answer. We are developing an interactive videos experience. I'm asked to track many user activities, such as video completion. Does the user reach 25%, 50%, 75% or 100% of each videos. We are feeding a Google Tag Manager DataLayer with those pieces of information. And using the MutationObserver, the completion event is sent multiple times. I will have a look at the onchnage and oninput event you mention :)

Comment: As a piece of information, I can't edit the html input to add onchange event. The html is generated by an authoring tool.

Comment: @Funambulum You can add an onchange event dynamically using `document.querySelector("[aria-valuetext]").addEventListener('change', function () { /* tracking code */ })`